# error : php bin/console doctrine:database:create

Tags: symfony

php bin/console doctrine:database:create

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

In PDOConnection.php line 50:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

In PDOConnection.php line 46:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]

amine@amine:/opt/lampp/htdocs/symphart$ sudo service apache2 restart
[sudo] password for amine:
amine@amine:/opt/lampp/htdocs/symphart$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

In PDOConnection.php line 50:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

In PDOConnection.php line 46:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]

Comment: People would save themselves so much effort if they just read some of the dozens of identical questions before posting yet another new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which symfony version is it ? I can see that you are using lampp, are the services running ? correct credentials (login / passowrd) ?

Comment: symfony 4 , i can't using lampp

Comment: do you have a .env file ? show the content please

Comment: .env : # This file is a "template" of which env vars need to be defined for your application# Copy this file to .env file for development, create environment variables when deploying to production
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#infrastructure-related-configuration

Comment: ###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=ad1dd169a4ab1b302c851db89f9e1710
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
#TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost,example.com
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

Comment: ###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
# For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
# For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="
# Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"
MAILER_URL=null://localhost
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###

Comment: ###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/symphart
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

Comment: check your root user password, or create a new user with a new password, with the right privileges on the symphart schema

Comment: same error, after the user change